# How to import password protected MS Access tables to excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

Without a password, I can easily import the access file, but when it is password protected, it just errors. The method i'm using is shown below: 
[Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4w1Y.png)

The error with a password protected file is shown below:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1qen.png)

The suggested method to open PW protected Access files are is:

```
Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\myDB.accdb"), False, False, "MS Access"; PWD="somePassword")
```

The issue now is:

The script shows that it will open the database using the hardcoded password, but how do I tell the Data -> Get Data -> From Database -> From Microsoft Access Database, to use that password when importing?

Comment: what about opening them in Access then exporting to Excel?

Comment: to your update: that works only if you write the whole import process in a macro, and can not be mixed with manual importing

Comment: That works fine as well. As long as it is capable of auto exporting tables to excel without need of human intervention. I don't know how to program using Access VBA that's why I sticked with the other way around. With regards to the macro, after a connection has been established between excel and access, you can create a refresh macro that will refresh the imported access tables. That's what I did but then the issue is that this one is password protected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to import data from a protected Access file using the GUI, you can use an OLEDB connection:

Go to *Data* ->  *Other sources* -> *From OLEDB*:

[image]

As your OLEDB string, enter:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Path\To\File.accdb";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="MyPassword";
```

Or, if you're using an MDB file:

```
Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="C:\Path\To\File.mdb";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="MyPassword";
```

Dropdown the *Advanced Options*, and in the box underneath, enter your query. E.g. if you want to import Table1:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

[image: SELECT * FROM Table1]

Then, press *OK*, view the data, and press *Load*. The data should now load.

Comment: After pressing OK I get another window and asks for credentials. Then it errors if I put random username and password

Comment: I've revised the answer. If you've set it up correctly, there should not be a prompt for credentials. You need the quotes if either your path or your password contains spaces. If your password contains quotes, double up those quotes (or choose a different password).

Comment: Thanks. I changed the .accdb to .mdb since that's my access file extention. Do I revert it back to .accdb?

Comment: That's kind of relevant information for your question. mdb is a format from over 10 years ago, I haven't tested my code for mdb files. Of course, you should use a valid path to your file.

Comment: This is my string it still asks for credentials: `provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source="C:\Users\Asus\Google Drive\System Improvement\Test.MDB";Jet OLEDB:database password="god";`

Comment: See the revised answer. I don't have much experience with JET. You might need to enter _Admin_ as username, and leave the password blank.

Comment: Yup that solved it. username Admin and PW left blank loads it. Thanks

Comment: I had to do an additional final step because the query would hang indefinitely. Right click on the query and select properties. Definition tab > Authentication Settings... and click None. This allows you to use the password in the connection string instead of the default which is AD login.